# Как повернуть и изменить размеры изображения в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, gui, tkinter

Одна из функций кнопок должна `поворачивать` изображение, 
а другая изменять (уменьшать/увеличивать) размер изображения.

Как это реализовать в *tkinter* ?

**main.py**:

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL, os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

while True:
    try:
        distanation = input('input pic dist>>>')
        if distanation == 'break':
            os.abort()
        pil_image = Image.open(distanation)
    except:
        print('cant find')
    else:
        input()
        break


#window options
window = Tk()
window.title('picture viewer(v0.14alpha)')
window.geometry('800x600')
window['bg'] = 'grey44'

for i in range(3):
    window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=70)
    window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=70)
#img
pil_image = pil_image.resize((700, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
pil_image.resize((18, 18))
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
image_sprite = Label(window, image=image)
image_sprite.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=8)

label_pic_name = Label(window, text=distanation, fg='#ccc',  bg='#555', font='Arial 14')                           
label_pic_name.grid(row=2, column=1)                            

#bottons_top
frame_top = Frame(window, width=100, height=100)
frame_top.grid(row=0, column=1)
btn1 = Button(frame_top, text="1111",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             relief = FLAT
             )
btn1.grid(row=0, column=1)

btn2 = Button(frame_top, text="2222",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             relief = FLAT
             )
btn2.grid(row=0, column=2)

btn3 = Button(frame_top, text="3333",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             relief = FLAT
             )
btn3.grid(row=0, column=3)

btn4 = Button(frame_top, text="4444",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             relief = FLAT
             )
btn4.grid(row=0, column=4)

#bottons_side
frame_side = Frame(window)
frame_side.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)
btn11 = Button(frame_side, text="1111",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             relief = FLAT
             )
btn11.grid(row=1, column=0)

btn22 = Button(frame_side, text="2222",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             relief = FLAT
             )
btn22.grid(row=2, column=0)

btn33 = Button(frame_side, text="3333",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             relief = FLAT
             )
btn33.grid(row=3, column=0)

btn44 = Button(frame_side, text="4444",        
             background="#555",  
             foreground="#ccc",     
             activebackground='#557',
             font="16",
             relief = FLAT
             )
btn44.grid(row=4, column=0)


#functions
#def fbtn1:
#def fbtn2:
#def fbtn3:
#def fbtn4:
#def fbtn11:
#def fbtn22:
#def fbtn33:
#def fbtn44:
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не сильно занимался оптимизацией и отладкой,
но основные моменты реализации - определил.

Установите стартовое изображение

```
#                      vvvvvvvvv
app = SimpleApp(root, 'lena2.png')
```

и попробуйте.

---

**main.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image


class SimpleApp(object):
    def __init__(self, master, filename, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        self.filename = filename
        self.pathToImage = ''
        self.canvas_obj = None
        
        for i in range(3):
            master.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=70)
            master.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=70)        
        
        self.label_pic_name = Label(self.master, text=self.filename, 
            fg='#ccc',  bg='#555', font='Arial 14')                           
        self.label_pic_name.grid(row=2, column=1) 

        # bottons_top ----------------------------------------
        frame_top = Frame(self.master, width=100, height=100)
        frame_top.grid(row=0, column=1)
        btn1 = Button(frame_top, text="+", background="#555",  
                     foreground="#ccc", activebackground='#557',
                     font="16", width = 5, relief = FLAT,
                     command=self.enlarge_image
                     )
        btn1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        btn2 = Button(frame_top, text="-", background="#555",
                     foreground="#ccc", activebackground='#557',
                     font="16", width = 5, relief = FLAT,
                     command=self.reduce_image
                     )
        btn2.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=1, pady=0)
        btn3 = Button(frame_top, text="3333", background="#555",  
                     foreground="#ccc", activebackground='#557',
                     font="16", width = 5, relief = FLAT
                     )
        btn3.grid(row=0, column=3)
        btn4 = Button(frame_top, text="4444", background="#555",  
                     foreground="#ccc", activebackground='#557',
                     font="16", width = 5, relief = FLAT
                     )
        btn4.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=1)

        # bottons_side ------------------------------------------
        frame_side = Frame(self.master)
        frame_side.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)
        btn11 = Button(frame_side, text=" << ", background="#555",  
                     foreground="#ccc", activebackground='#557',
                     font="16", width=5, relief=FLAT,
                     command=self.image_counter_clockwise
                     )
        btn11.grid(row=1, column=0)
        btn22 = Button(frame_side, text=" >> ", background="#555",  
                     foreground="#ccc", activebackground='#557',
                     font="16", width = 5, relief = FLAT,
                     command=self.image_clockwise
                     )
        btn22.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=1)
        btn33 = Button(frame_side, text="3333", background="#555",  
                     foreground="#ccc", activebackground='#557',
                     font="16", width = 5, relief = FLAT
                     )
        btn33.grid(row=3, column=0)
        btn44 = Button(frame_side, text="4444", background="#555",  
                     foreground="#ccc", activebackground='#557',
                     font="16", width = 5, relief = FLAT
                     )
        btn44.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=1)

        # butSelect ------------------------------------------
        butSelect = Button(self.master, 
            text='Select PNG', command=self.but_select) 
        butSelect.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.canvas = Canvas(master, 
            width=700, height=500, bg="#707070", highlightthickness=0)
        self.tkimage = Image.open(self.filename)
        self.canvas.grid(row=1, column=1, 
                         padx=10, pady=10,
                         ipadx=0, ipady=0,
        )
        
        self.update = self.draw(number_cycles=38).__next__
        master.after(500, self.update)
   
    # draw ------------------------------------------
    def draw(self, number_cycles=0):
        image = Image.open(self.filename)
        angle = 0
        i = 0
        flag = True
        while flag: 
            i += 1
            if i < number_cycles:
                tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.rotate(angle))
                self.canvas_obj = self.canvas.create_image(
                    350, 250, image=tkimage)
                self.master.after_idle(self.update)
                yield
                if i < number_cycles-1:
                    self.canvas.delete(self.canvas_obj)
                angle += 10
                angle %= 360
            else: 
                yield
                flag = False

    # but_select image -------------------------------------               
    def but_select(self):
        self.select_image()          

    def select_image(self):
        pathToImage = filedialog.askopenfilename(
            filetypes=[('PNG Files','*.png'),('JPG Files','*.jpg'),
                       ('JPEG Files','*.jpeg')])
                       
        if not pathToImage: return 
        
        image = Image.open(str(pathToImage)) 
        w, h = image.size      
        if w > 650:
            k = w/650
            _w = int(w/k)
            _h = int(h/k)
            image = image.resize((_w, _h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        w, h = image.size 
        if h > 450:
            k = h/450
            _w = int(w/k)
            _h = int(h/k)
            image = image.resize((_w, _h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.tkimage = image                              

        image = self.make_square(im=image)        
        w, h = image.size                          
        if w > 700:
            k = w/700
            _w = int(w/k)
            _h = int(h/k)
            image = image.resize((_w, _h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        w, h = image.size 
        if h > 500:
            k = h/500
            _w = int(w/k)
            _h = int(h/k)
            image = image.resize((_w, _h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        w, h = image.size
        
        self.selectedImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)   
        self.canvas.delete(self.canvas_obj)
        self.canvas_obj = self.canvas.create_image(       
            (700-w)//2, (500-h)//2, 
            anchor=NW, image=self.selectedImage
        )        
        self.label_pic_name['text'] = pathToImage
 
    def make_square(self, im, min_size=256, fill_color = (112, 112, 112)):    
        x, y = im.size
        size = max(min_size, x, y)
        new_im = Image.new('RGBA', (size,size), (112, 112, 112, 255))        
        new_im.paste(im, (int((size - x) / 2), int((size - y) / 2)))
        return new_im
 
    def image_counter_clockwise(self):
        self.update = self.draw2(number_cycles=11).__next__
        self.master.after(100, self.update)
        
    def image_clockwise(self):
        self.update = self.draw2(number_cycles=11, delta_angle=-10).__next__
        self.master.after(100, self.update)

    def draw2(self, number_cycles=0, delta_angle=10):
        image = self.tkimage
        self.canvas.delete(self.canvas_obj)
        angle = 0
        i = 0
        flag = True
        while flag: 
            i += 1
            if i < number_cycles:
                tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.rotate(angle))
                self.canvas_obj = self.canvas.create_image(
                    350, 250, image=tkimage)
                self.master.after_idle(self.update)
                yield
                
                if i < number_cycles-1:
                    self.canvas.delete(self.canvas_obj)
                
                self.tkimage = image.rotate(angle)                 
                angle += delta_angle         
                angle %= 360
            else: 
                yield
                flag = False

    def enlarge_image(self):
        w, h = self.tkimage.size                    
        _w, _h = int(w * 1.1), int(h * 1.1)
        if _w >= 700 or _h >= 500:
            return
        image = self.tkimage.resize((_w, _h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.selectedImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)
        self.canvas.delete(self.canvas_obj)
        self.canvas_obj = self.canvas.create_image(       
            (700-_w)//2, (500-_h)//2,                      
            anchor=NW, image=self.selectedImage
        )          
        self.tkimage = image 

    def reduce_image(self):
        w, h = self.tkimage.size                    
        _w, _h = int(w // 1.1), int(h // 1.1)
        if _w <= 140 or _h <= 100:
            return
        image = self.tkimage.resize((_w, _h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.selectedImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)
        self.canvas.delete(self.canvas_obj)
        self.canvas_obj = self.canvas.create_image(       
            (700-_w)//2, (500-_h)//2,                      
            anchor=NW, image=self.selectedImage
        )          
        self.tkimage = image 


root = Tk()
root['bg'] = 'grey44'
app = SimpleApp(root, 'lena2.png')
root.mainloop()
```

---

**lena2.png**

**[image: lena2.png]**

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]