# Загрузка изображения на выбор и вывод на Canvas

Tags: python, изображения, tkinter, canvas, filedialog

Делаю `paint` на питоне и столкнулся с проблемой. 
Попытался сделать загрузку **`.png`** и **`.jpg`** форматов
код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

canvas_width = 700
canvas_height = 500
brush_size = 3
color = "black"


def save():
    fn = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialfile="Untitled.png", filetypes=[("PNG", ".png"), ("JPG", ".jpg")], initialdir="Computer/Images")
    if fn == "":
        return


def load():
    fl = filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[("PNG", ".png"), ("JPG", ".jpg")])
    w.create_image(canvas_width, canvas_height, image=fl, anchor=NW)


def paint(event):
    global brush_size
    global color
    x1 = event.x - brush_size
    x2 = event.x + brush_size
    y1 = event.y - brush_size
    y2 = event.y + brush_size
    w.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2,
                  fill=color,
                  outline=color)


def brush_size_change(new_size):
    global brush_size
    brush_size = new_size


def color_change(new_color):
    global color
    color = new_color


root = Tk()
root.title("Paint")

w = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width,
           height=canvas_height, bg="white")

w.bind("<B1-Motion>", paint)

col = Label(root, text="Цвет кисти")
col.grid(row=0, column=0)

size = Label(root, text="Размер кисти")
size.grid(row=8, column=0)

save_btn = Button(text="Сохранить", width=8, command=lambda: save())
load_btn = Button(text="Загрузить", width=8, command=lambda: load())
ten_btn = Button(text="Размер 10", width=8, command=lambda: brush_size_change(10))
five_btn = Button(text="Размер 5", width=8, command=lambda: brush_size_change(5))
two_btn = Button(text="Размер 3", width=8, command=lambda: brush_size_change(3))
fiveten_btn = Button(text="Размер 15", width=8, command=lambda: brush_size_change(15))

yellow_btn = Button(text="Жёлтый", width=10, command=lambda: color_change("yellow"))
brown_btn = Button(text="Коричневый", width=10, command=lambda: color_change("brown"))
black_btn = Button(text="Черный", width=10, command=lambda: color_change("black"))
red_btn = Button(text="Красный", width=10, command=lambda: color_change("red"))
green_btn = Button(text="Зеленый", width=10, command=lambda: color_change("green"))
white_btn = Button(text="Ластик", width=10, command=lambda: color_change("white"))
clear_btn = Button(text="Удалить всё", width=10, command=lambda: w.delete("all"))

w.grid(row=2, column=0,
       columnspan=7, padx=5,
       pady=5, sticky=E + W + S + N)
w.columnconfigure(6, weight=1)
w.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

save_btn.grid(row=8, column=5)
two_btn.grid(row=8, column=1)
five_btn.grid(row=8, column=2)
ten_btn.grid(row=8, column=3)
fiveten_btn.grid(row=8, column=4)

yellow_btn.grid(row=0, column=7)
brown_btn.grid(row=0, column=6)
clear_btn.grid(row=0, column=5)
white_btn.grid(row=0, column=4)
green_btn.grid(row=0, column=3)
black_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)
red_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)

load()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Меня очень смущает такое обилие глобальных переменных. Вы бы попробовали переписать все с использованием ООП, как пример [Как повернуть и изменить размеры изображения в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1301559/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-tkinter/1306740#1306740)

Ну, а теперь попробуйте ваш, немного измененный код.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

from PIL import ImageTk, Image                                   # +++

canvas_width = 700
canvas_height = 500
brush_size = 3
color = "black"


def save():
    fn = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialfile="Untitled.png", filetypes=[("PNG", ".png"), ("JPG", ".jpg")], initialdir="Computer/Images")
    if fn == "":
        return

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
def make_square(im, min_size=256, fill_color = (112, 112, 112)):    
    x, y = im.size
    size = max(min_size, x, y)
    new_im = Image.new('RGBA', (size,size), (255, 255, 255, 255))        
    new_im.paste(im, (int((size - x) / 2), int((size - y) / 2)))
    return new_im

def load():
    global canvas_obj, tkimage, selectedImage
#    fl = filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[("PNG", ".png"), ("JPG", ".jpg")])
# ??? TclError: image "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='D:/_Qt/__Qt/lena.jpg' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>" 
#  doesn't exi
#    w.create_image(canvas_width, canvas_height, image=fl, anchor=NW)

    pathToImage = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        filetypes=[('PNG Files','*.png'),('JPG Files','*.jpg'),
                   ('JPEG Files','*.jpeg')])
                   
    if not pathToImage: return 
    
    image = Image.open(str(pathToImage)) 
    w, h = image.size      
    if w > 650:
        k = w/650
        _w = int(w/k)
        _h = int(h/k)
        image = image.resize((_w, _h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    w, h = image.size 
    if h > 450:
        k = h/450
        _w = int(w/k)
        _h = int(h/k)
        image = image.resize((_w, _h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    tkimage = image                              

    image = make_square(im=image)        
    w, h = image.size                          
    if w > 700:
        k = w/700
        _w = int(w/k)
        _h = int(h/k)
        image = image.resize((_w, _h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    w, h = image.size 
    if h > 500:
        k = h/500
        _w = int(w/k)
        _h = int(h/k)
        image = image.resize((_w, _h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    w, h = image.size    
    
    
    selectedImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=image)   
    canvas.delete(canvas_obj)
    canvas_obj = canvas.create_image(       
        (700-w)//2, (500-h)//2,
        anchor=NW, image=selectedImage 
    ) 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    

def paint(event):
    global brush_size
    global color
    x1 = event.x - brush_size
    x2 = event.x + brush_size
    y1 = event.y - brush_size
    y2 = event.y + brush_size
    canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2,
                  fill=color,
                  outline=color)

def brush_size_change(new_size):
    global brush_size
    brush_size = new_size

def color_change(new_color):
    global color
    color = new_color

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
def draw(filename, number_cycles=0):
    global canvas_obj, update, tkimage
    image = Image.open(filename)
    angle = 0
    i = 0
    flag = True
    while flag: 
        i += 1
        if i < number_cycles:
            tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.rotate(angle))
            canvas_obj = canvas.create_image(
                350, 250, image=tkimage)
            root.after_idle(update)
            yield
            if i < number_cycles-1:
                canvas.delete(canvas_obj)
            angle += 10
            angle %= 360
        else: 
            yield
            flag = False
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          

root = Tk()
root.title("Paint")

#vvvvv <---- canvas # !!!
#w = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width,
canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width,
           height=canvas_height, bg="white")
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", paint)

col = Label(root, text="Цвет кисти")
col.grid(row=0, column=0)

size = Label(root, text="Размер кисти")
size.grid(row=8, column=0)

save_btn = Button(text="Сохранить", width=8, command=lambda: save())
load_btn = Button(text="Загрузить", width=8, command=lambda: load())
ten_btn = Button(text="Размер 10", width=8, command=lambda: brush_size_change(10))
five_btn = Button(text="Размер 5", width=8, command=lambda: brush_size_change(5))
two_btn = Button(text="Размер 3", width=8, command=lambda: brush_size_change(3))
fiveten_btn = Button(text="Размер 15", width=8, command=lambda: brush_size_change(15))

yellow_btn = Button(text="Жёлтый", width=10, command=lambda: color_change("yellow"))
brown_btn = Button(text="Коричневый", width=10, command=lambda: color_change("brown"))
black_btn = Button(text="Черный", width=10, command=lambda: color_change("black"))
red_btn = Button(text="Красный", width=10, command=lambda: color_change("red"))
green_btn = Button(text="Зеленый", width=10, command=lambda: color_change("green"))
white_btn = Button(text="Ластик", width=10, command=lambda: color_change("white"))
clear_btn = Button(text="Удалить всё", width=10, command=lambda: w.delete("all"))


canvas.grid(row=2, column=0,
       columnspan=7, padx=5,
       pady=5, sticky=E + W + S + N)
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
canvas_obj = None
selectedImage = None
filename = 'lena.jpg'                   # можете установить свое изображение
tkimage = Image.open(filename)
update = draw(filename, number_cycles=38).__next__
root.after(500, update)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       
canvas.columnconfigure(6, weight=1)
canvas.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

save_btn.grid(row=8, column=5)
two_btn.grid(row=8, column=1)
five_btn.grid(row=8, column=2)
ten_btn.grid(row=8, column=3)
fiveten_btn.grid(row=8, column=4)

yellow_btn.grid(row=0, column=7)
brown_btn.grid(row=0, column=6)
clear_btn.grid(row=0, column=5)
white_btn.grid(row=0, column=4)
green_btn.grid(row=0, column=3)
black_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)
red_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)

# load()
root.after(2000, load)                                    # +++

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**lena.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @GameTime что не так?

Comment: всё отлично работает спасибо!

Comment: но почему то функция загрузки вызывается при запуске и если я закрываю окно с открытием файла то вся программа закрывается и вылезает несколько ошибок

Comment: @GameTime Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.