# Как повернуть картинку в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
r = Tk()

r.title('Tic-Tac-Toe')
r.iconphoto(True,PhotoImage(file='ttt icon.png'))
r.geometry('524x519')
r.resizable(0,0)

Go = 0; Gx = 1; turn = 'X'; win = ''
asd = Label(text='X turn', font=('20px'))
asd.grid(row=0,column=1)
def click00():
    global Gx, Go, turn, win
    if Gx == 1:
        button00.config(text='X',state='disable')
        Go = 1
        Gx = 0
        turn = 'O'
        if button00['text'] == 'X' and button01['text'] == 'X' and button02['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=110)
        if button00['text'] == 'X' and button10['text'] == 'X' and button20['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=86)
        if button00['text'] == 'X' and button11['text'] == 'X' and button22['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
    elif Go == 1:
        button00.config(text='O',state='disable')
        Gx = 1
        Go = 0
        turn = 'X'
        if button00['text'] == 'O' and button01['text']  == 'O' and button02['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=110)
        if button00['text'] == 'O' and button10['text'] == 'O' and button20['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=86)
        if button00['text'] == 'O' and button11['text'] == 'O' and button22['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
    if turn == 'X':
        label = Label(text='X turn', font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
    elif turn == 'O':
        label = Label(text='O turn',font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
        if win == 'X':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
        if win == 'O':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
def click01():
    global Gx, Go, turn,win
    if Gx == 1:
        button01.config(text='X',state='disable')
        Go = 1
        Gx = 0
        turn = 'O'
        if button00['text'] == 'X' and button01['text'] == 'X' and button02['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=110)
        if button01['text'] == 'X' and button11['text'] == 'X' and button21['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=261)
    elif Go == 1:
        button01.config(text='O',state='disable')
        Gx = 1
        Go = 0
        turn = 'X'
        if button00['text'] == 'O' and button01['text'] == 'O' and button02['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=110)
        if button01['text'] == 'O' and button11['text'] == 'O' and button21['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=261)
    if turn == 'X':
        label = Label(text='X turn', font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
    elif turn == 'O':
        label = Label(text='O turn',font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
        if win == 'X':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
        if win == 'O':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
def click02():
    global Gx, Go, turn, win
    if Gx == 1:
        button02.config(text='X',state='disable')
        Go = 1
        Gx = 0
        turn = 'O'
        if button00['text'] == 'X' and button01['text'] == 'X' and button02['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=110)
        if button02['text'] == 'X' and button12['text'] == 'X' and button22['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=438)
        if button02['text'] == 'X' and button11['text'] == 'X' and button20['text'] == 'X':
            print('X WIN')
    elif Go == 1:
        button02.config(text='O',state='disable')
        Gx = 1
        Go = 0
        turn = 'X'
        if button00['text'] == 'O' and button01['text'] == 'O' and button02['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=110)
        if button02['text'] == 'O' and button12['text'] == 'O' and button22['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=438)
        if button02['text'] == 'O' and button11['text'] == 'O' and button20['text'] == 'O':
            print('O WIN')
    if turn == 'X':
        label = Label(text='X turn', font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
    elif turn == 'O':
        label = Label(text='O turn',font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
        if win == 'X':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
        if win == 'O':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
def click10():
    global Gx, Go, turn, win
    if Gx == 1:
        button10.config(text='X',state='disable')
        Go = 1
        Gx = 0
        turn = 'O'
        if button10['text'] == 'X' and button11['text'] == 'X' and button12['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=290)
        if button00['text'] == 'X' and button10['text'] == 'X' and button20['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=86)
    elif Go == 1:
        button10.config(text='O',state='disable')
        Gx = 1
        Go = 0
        turn = 'X'
        if button10['text'] == 'O' and button11['text'] == 'O' and button12['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=290)
        if button00['text'] == 'O' and button10['text'] == 'O' and button20['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=86)
    if turn == 'X':
        label = Label(text='X turn', font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
    elif turn == 'O':
        label = Label(text='O turn',font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
        if win == 'X':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
        if win == 'O':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
def click11():
    global Gx, Go, turn, win
    if Gx == 1:
        button11.config(text='X',state='disable')
        Go = 1
        Gx = 0
        turn = 'O'
        if button10['text'] == 'X' and button11['text'] == 'X' and button12['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=290)
        if button01['text'] == 'X' and button11['text'] == 'X' and button21['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=261)
        if button00['text'] == 'X' and button11['text'] == 'X' and button22['text'] == 'X':
            print('X WIN')
        if button02['text'] == 'X' and button11['text'] == 'X' and button20['text'] == 'X':
            print('X WIN')
    elif Go == 1:
        button11.config(text='O',state='disable')
        Gx = 1
        Go = 0
        turn = 'X'
        if button10['text'] == 'O' and button11['text'] == 'O' and button12['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=290)
        if button01['text'] == 'O' and button11['text'] == 'O' and button21['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=261)
        if button00['text'] == 'O' and button11['text'] == 'O' and button22['text'] == 'O':
            print('O WIN')
        if button02['text'] == 'O' and button11['text'] == 'O' and button20['text'] == 'O':
            print('O WIN')
    if turn == 'X':
        label = Label(text='X turn', font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
    elif turn == 'O':
        label = Label(text='O turn',font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
        if win == 'X':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
        if win == 'O':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
def click12():
    global Gx, Go, turn, win
    if Gx == 1:
        button12.config(text='X',state='disable')
        Go = 1
        Gx = 0
        turn = 'O'
        if button10['text'] == 'X' and button11['text'] == 'X' and button12['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=290)
        if button02['text'] == 'X' and button12['text'] == 'X' and button22['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=438)
    elif Go == 1:
        button12.config(text='O',state='disable')
        Gx = 1
        Go = 0
        turn = 'X'
        if button10['text'] == 'O' and button11['text'] == 'O' and button12['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=290)
        if button02['text'] == 'O' and button12['text'] == 'O' and button22['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=438)
    if turn == 'X':
        label = Label(text='X turn', font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
    elif turn == 'O':
        label = Label(text='O turn',font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
        if win == 'X':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
        if win == 'O':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
def click20():
    global Gx, Go, turn, win
    if Gx == 1:
        button20.config(text='X',state='disable')
        Go = 1
        Gx = 0
        turn = 'O'
        if button20['text'] == 'X' and button21['text'] == 'X' and button22['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=471)
        if button00['text'] == 'X' and button10['text'] == 'X' and button20['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=86)
        if button02['text'] == 'X' and button11['text'] == 'X' and button20['text'] == 'X':
            print('X WIN')
    elif Go == 1:
        button20.config(text='O',state='disable')
        Gx = 1
        Go = 0
        turn = 'X'
        if button20['text'] == 'O' and button21['text'] == 'O' and button22['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=471)
        if button00['text'] == 'O' and button10['text'] == 'O' and button20['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=86)
        if button02['text'] == 'O' and button11['text'] == 'O' and button20['text'] == 'O':
            print('O WIN')
    if turn == 'X':
        label = Label(text='X turn', font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
    elif turn == 'O':
        label = Label(text='O turn',font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
        if win == 'X':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
        if win == 'O':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
def click21():
    global Gx, Go, turn, win
    if Gx == 1:
        button21.config(text='X',state='disable')
        Go = 1
        Gx = 0
        turn = 'O'
        if button20['text'] == 'X' and button21['text'] == 'X' and button22['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=471)
        if button01['text'] == 'X' and button11['text'] == 'X' and button21['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=261)
    elif Go == 1:
        button21.config(text='O',state='disable')
        Gx = 1
        Go = 0
        turn = 'X'
        if button20['text'] == 'O' and button21['text'] == 'O' and button22['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=471)
        if button01['text'] == 'O' and button11['text'] == 'O' and button21['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=261)
    if turn == 'X':
        label = Label(text='X turn', font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
    elif turn == 'O':
        label = Label(text='O turn',font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
        if win == 'X':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
        if win == 'O':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
def click22():
    global Gx, Go, turn, win
    if Gx == 1:
        button22.config(text='X', state='disable')
        Go = 1
        Gx = 0
        turn = 'O'
        if button20['text'] == 'X' and button21['text'] == 'X' and button22['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=471)
        if button02['text'] == 'X' and button12['text'] == 'X' and button22['text'] == 'X':
            win = 'X'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=438)
        if button00['text'] == 'X' and button11['text'] == 'X' and button22['text'] == 'X':
            print('X WIN')
    elif Go == 1:
        button22.config(text='O',state='disable')
        Gx = 1
        Go = 0
        turn = 'X'
        if button20['text'] == 'O' and button21['text'] == 'O' and button22['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='гпоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(x=88,y=471)
        if button02['text'] == 'O' and button12['text'] == 'O' and button22['text'] == 'O':
            win = 'O'
            gpob = PhotoImage(file='впоб.png')
            gpobL = Label(border=0, image=gpob,bg='red')
            gpobL.place(y=117,x=438)
        if button00['text'] == 'O' and button11['text'] == 'O' and button22['text'] == 'O':
            print('O WIN')
    if turn == 'X':
        label = Label(text='X turn', font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
    elif turn == 'O':
        label = Label(text='O turn',font=('20px'))
        label.grid(row=0,column=1)
        if win == 'X':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')
        if win == 'O':
            button00.config(state='disable')
            button01.config(state='disable')
            button02.config(state='disable')
            button10.config(state='disable')
            button11.config(state='disable')
            button12.config(state='disable')
            button20.config(state='disable')
            button21.config(state='disable')
            button22.config(state='disable')

button00 = Button(bd=0,activebackground='#00eeff',width=10,height=5,bg='#00eeff', command=click00, font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))
button01 = Button(bd=0,activebackground='#00eeff',width=10,height=5,bg='#00eeff', command=click01, font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))
button02 = Button(bd=0,activebackground='#00eeff',width=10,height=5,bg='#00eeff', command=click02, font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))

button10 = Button(bd=0,activebackground='#00eeff',width=10,height=5,bg='#00eeff', command=click10, font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))
button11 = Button(bd=0,activebackground='#00eeff',width=10,height=5,bg='#00eeff', command=click11, font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))
button12 = Button(bd=0,activebackground='#00eeff',width=10,height=5,bg='#00eeff', command=click12, font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))

button20 = Button(bd=0,activebackground='#00eeff',width=10,height=5,bg='#00eeff', command=click20, font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))
button21 = Button(bd=0,activebackground='#00eeff',width=10,height=5,bg='#00eeff', command=click21, font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))
button22 = Button(bd=0,activebackground='#00eeff',width=10,height=5,bg='#00eeff', command=click22, font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))

button00.grid(row=1,column=0)
button01.grid(row=1,column=1)
button02.grid(row=1,column=2)

button10.grid(row=2,column=0)
button11.grid(row=2,column=1)
button12.grid(row=2,column=2)

button20.grid(row=3,column=0)
button21.grid(row=3,column=1)
button22.grid(row=3,column=2)

line0 = PhotoImage(file='верт.png')
line0L = Label(image=line0,border=0)
line0L.place(x=173,y=30)

line1 = PhotoImage(file='верт.png')
line1L = Label(image=line1,border=0)
line1L.place(x=353,y=30)

line2 = PhotoImage(file='гориз.png')
line2L = Label(image=line2,border=0)
line2L.place(x=-66,y=180)

line3 = PhotoImage(file='гориз.png')
line3L = Label(image=line3,border=0)
line3L.place(x=-66,y=360)

r.mainloop()
```

Comment: С помощью библиотеки PIL (Pillow). В tkinter встроенных средств для поворота картинок нет.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1301559/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-tkinter/1306740#1306740

Comment: а как добавить картинку на экран с помощью PIL

Comment: @Codex "добавить на экран" можно с помощью tkinter. Но если перед этим нужно повернуть - это делается с помощью PIL, в памяти, а не на экране.